# Concurrent update in mysql row using trigger

Tags: java, mysql, web-services, concurrency

I have a soap-based web service with Java + Mysql.

The web services consist in save and send as a response generated documents. Each user has a limited number of documents available. This service provide documents to external systems, so, i have to know the documents available any time for an specific user.

To improve this a build a trigger that updates the user row when a new document is created.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `Service`.`discount_doc_fromplan`
AFTER INSERT ON `Service`.`Doc` FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE `Service`.`User` SET User.DocAvailable = User.DocAvailable - 1 where User.id = NEW.idUser
```

The problem comes when an user tries to create 2 or more documents at the same time because of their systems. This give me a "Deadlock found when trying to get lock".

Somebody has an idea to improve this without the deadlock problem and at the same time the right number of documents available?. This is my first web service. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to implement your business logic inside a database trigger. Instead of trigger, you can implement this logic in either (1) your web service application middleware or (2) a stored procedure. I prefer approach (1) though. The basic code in either will collect all inserts in `Doc` table by a user in a cumulative counter and at the end of all inserts, update the `User` table `DocAvailable = DocAvailable -counter` in one go. You can do this in a transaction so that you can rollback in case of a problem. You will have to read the available `Doc quota` for the `user` before starting the transaction.